# conditionally render data in an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, render, native

So i want to conditionally render an item from an API im working with. i.e. if the `title={item.title}` returns an empty data, then the application should render title as something like a string. here's the code, thanks in advance!

**the code im working with:**

```
const getArticles = () => {
  axios
    .get(
      "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=API-KEY",
      {
        params: {
          category: "technology",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      setArticles(response.data.articles);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {});
};

useEffect(() => {
    getArticles();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={articles}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Artikel
            urlToImage={item.urlToImage}
            title={item.title}
            description={item.description}
            author={item.author}
            publishedAt={item.publishedAt}
            sourceName={item.source.name}
            url={item.url}
            content={item.content}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

**this is the card component where i use the datas i've rendered:**

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <Pressable onPress={() => goToDetail(props)}>
    <Image
      style={styles.image}
      on
      source={{
        uri: props.urlToImage,
      }}
    />
  </Pressable>
  <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, paddingBottom: 10 }}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.deskripsi} numberOfLines={3}>
      {props.description}
    </Text>
    <View style={styles.data}>
      <Text style={styles.h2}>
        source:<Text style={styles.sumber}> {props.sourceName}</Text>
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.tanggal}>
        {moment(props.publishedAt).format("MMM Do YY")}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

i'd love if the datas return an empty value the application would render something else i manually made (i.e. strings)

Comment: You can try like `title={item.title || 'Some other title'}` .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what are you trying to achieve, use conditional rendering using ternary operator:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <Pressable onPress={() => goToDetail(props)}>
    <Image
      style={styles.image}
      on
      source={{
        uri: props.urlToImage,
      }}
    />
  </Pressable>
  <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, paddingBottom: 10 }}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{!!props.title ? : props.title : "empty title placeholder"}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.deskripsi} numberOfLines={3}>
      {props.description}
    </Text>
    <View style={styles.data}>
      <Text style={styles.h2}>
        source:<Text style={styles.sumber}> {props.sourceName}</Text>
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.tanggal}>
        {moment(props.publishedAt).format("MMM Do YY")}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```